# IMDB api actor information

Tags: json, request, imdb

Good evening,

I'm trying to gather information about an actor (the movies he acted in). I'm using the IMBD Api, which isn't very well documented.
By sending an request like this I can get the ID of the actor:

[http://www.imdb.com/xml/find?json=1&nr=1&nm=on&q=emma+watson](http://www.imdb.com/xml/find?json=1&nr=1&nm=on&q=emma%20watson)

Question is how do I get the information about the actor, namely his movies?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this api, they have movie search / movie posters / and Actor biography as well

http://www.theimdbapi.org/